# GitHub Actions dotnet build Unable to find package

Tags: github, nuget, github-actions

I have a .NET CI ins GitHub Actions. Before added Dapper.FluentMap to the project, the GitHub Action was working without any errors.

GitHub Actions fails on:

*- name: Build with dotnet*

*run: dotnet build --configuration Release*

How can I build on GitHub actions using a NuGet Dapper.FluentMap dependency ?

I am now getting an error in GitBub Actions:

```
D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\BLL\BLL.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Dapper.FluentMap. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement.sln]
D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\WebApp\WebApp.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Dapper.FluentMap. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement.sln]
  Failed to restore D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\WebApp\WebApp.csproj (in 316 ms).
  Failed to restore D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\BLL\BLL.csproj (in 313 ms).
D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\DAL\DAL.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Dapper.FluentMap. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement.sln]
  Failed to restore D:\a\esta-uploadmanagement\esta-uploadmanagement\DAL\DAL.csproj (in 1 ms).
```

My Yaml file

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'
      
    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

Comment: Looks like you only defined a local nuget repository in your solution and the nuget repo is not part of your git repo and therefor not available in your GitHub actions workflow.

Comment: @riQQ  "the nuget repo is not part of your git repo..." Do you have an example OR link to solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a recent bug / issue, as reported [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/issues/184) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/10171) on GitHub.

You can work around this issue by manually adding the nuget.org as source in a step:

```
[...]
    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'

    # new step
    - name: Add nuget.org as nuget package source
      run: dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --name nuget.org

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release
[...]
```

Comment: I have the same **error** but it's using *github nuget package*. Although it's authenticated, it can't find packagest using `donet restore`

Answer (score 0):

you can search some special command to deal with it. For example you should be allowed to committed resource from different history.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).