# Github Actions cannot find NuGet package hosted in GitHub Packages

Tags: nuget, github-actions

I have a GitHub organisation set up and within that are two private repositories: Library and App. I have managed to configure a GitHub Action for the Library repository to create a NuGet package and push it to `nuget.pkg.github.com`. I added the Library package as a dependency to the App project and can fetch these locally using a configured Personal Access Token. I am now working on the GitHub Action to build and run unit tests on the App project.

I have added a step to the workflow to add the NuGet package source

```
- name: Set package source
  run: dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/REDACTED/index.json"
```

This is exactly the same line as is used when pushing the package, but when I reach the `dotnet restore` step later I get the following error:

```
/home/runner/work/App/App/App.Services/App.Services.csproj : error NU1101:
Unable to find package Library. No packages exist with this id in source(s): github, nuget.org [/home/runner/work/App/App/App.sln]
```

I understand that it is likely possible to work around this by adding a new Personal Access Token to the secrets of the App repository, but would prefer to rely on GITHUB_TOKEN if possible for both the security and management benefits.

According to GitHub, [installing packages hosted with GitHub Packages requires minimal configuration using GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions#installing-a-package-using-an-action). And by default, [GITHUB_TOKEN has both read and write permissions for packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token).

This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052324/github-actions-dotnet-build-unable-to-find-package) as that relates to an issue with empty NuGet.config files which has since been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same problem, GITHUB_TOKEN can be used to push packages but not pull packages from other repos within the same organisation. This thread has a lot of people complaining about it: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/49. I was unable to get any of the workarounds there working for me, and had no option in GitHub to grant specific permissions to repositories in the organisation for packages. Had to use a PAT in the end.